# "Unable to retrieve correct enclosing instance of this" error in Android?

Tags: java, android

In the below given function i am trying to **create an alertDialog box with username and password field** and **Insert the values of the fields into the shared preferences**.But the **app crashes after i press the ok button in alert dialog box after entering the fields**

I am not able to access the variables inside the alertDialog box positive button click listener inside the protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id).When I inspect the variables 
prefs,username and password it shows me this.
**Unable to retrieve correct enclosing instance of this.** Can someone tell me what is the reason for this

```
       import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.app.Dialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
        import android.content.SharedPreferences;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.EditText;

        public class Login extends Activity {

            public static String PREF_LOGIN_USERNAME = "pref_username";
            public static String PREF_LOGIN_PASSWORD = "pref_password";

            public static final int DIALOG_LOGIN = 100;
            public static final int DIALOG_NEW_PASSWORD = 101;


            LayoutInflater factory;
            View loginView;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);

            }

            protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
                switch (id) {

                case DIALOG_LOGIN:
                    // Inflating the View from the xml
                    factory = LayoutInflater.from(Login.this);
                    loginView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
                    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_login)
                            .setView(loginView)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                       Context context = getApplicationContext();
                            SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                                    EditText username = (EditText)loginView.findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
                                    EditText password = (EditText)loginView.findViewById(R.id.password_edit);
                                    editor.putString(PREF_LOGIN_USERNAME,
                                            username.getText().toString());
                                    editor.putString(PREF_LOGIN_PASSWORD,
                                            password.getText().toString());
                                    editor.commit();
                                    editor.commit();


                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel,
                                    new OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
                                        }
                                    }).create();
    }
    return null;
        }
    }
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/username_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:text="@string/alert_dialog_username"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_edit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:text="@string/alert_dialog_password"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:password="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Error log from ddms:

```
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 21:43:32.870: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at com.qrcoder.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:66)
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
04-14 21:43:32.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16125):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit**:This is the working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on, but I'd suggest moving the call to `showDialog` out of `onCreate`. It's probably better to do it in `onResume`, when the UI is actually on the screen.

**EDIT** Okay, I think I see what's going on. You are trying to initialize the fields username and password in the onCreate method for your activity, but I'm guessing that these fields only exist in the login dialog. You need to find the fields after you construct the dialog itself, since they don't exist before that.

Comment: Did that.Still getting the same problem.
Updated the log file .please have a look at that.

Comment: @Tedd:Thanks for all the help.The code is working now.I have edited it.It needed a bit more than what you said.I am now initialising all the variables inside the onclick function.The problem also existed for the shared preference variable also.I don't understand why it is not able to find the global variable's reference.Can you shed some light on this.

Comment: @rogerstone - do you mean that the compiler complained about the shared preference variable when it was in the outer class, or that you got a null pointer or other exception when dereferencing it from within the OnClickListener?

Comment: @Tedd:While debugging I inspected(or watch) the shared preference variable and got this message "Unable to retrieve correct enclosing instance of this".

Comment: @rogerstone - I think that means that Eclipse got confused about something. (This is not my strong suit; perhaps someone else can shed some light on this.) Does the message affect program execution or just the debugger?

Comment: @Tedd:I guess it was not able to recognise some of the  global variables inside the onclick function.It did not affect the debugger it just meant that it is unable to recognise the value of that variable.The behaviour seems strange.